# Не понимаю какой параметр передавать в адаптер, если там имплимитирован интерфейс в конструктор

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Здравсвуйте, столкнулся с проблемой в RecyclerView,выводит нормально, реакция на кнопку из айтема есть, но как передать, то что кнопка была нажата во фрагмент или активити?

Код адаптера

```
class DataAdapter(private val list: MutableList<Recept>, private val click: Click?)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<fragment5.MovieViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): fragment5.MovieViewHolder {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return fragment5.MovieViewHolder(inflater, parent)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: fragment5.MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val movie: Recept = list[position]
        holder.bind(movie)

        holder.itemView.editReceptItem.setOnClickListener{

            click?.sendData()
        }


    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

}
```

Код холдера:

```kotlin
    class MovieViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_recept, parent, false)) {
            private var mName: TextView? = null
            private var mFormula: TextView? = null

            init {

               
                mButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editReceptItem);

            }
            fun bind(movie: Recept) {

                mName?.text = movie.name
                mFormula?.text = movie.ingridients

                mButton?.setOnClickListener{


                    STORAGE_FOR_RECYCLE_RECEPT.name=movie.name
                    STORAGE_FOR_RECYCLE_RECEPT.formula=movie.formula
                    STORAGE_FOR_RECYCLE_RECEPT.ingridients=movie.ingridients
                    STORAGE_FOR_RECYCLE_RECEPT.photo=movie.photoSrc
                    STORAGE_FOR_RECYCLE_RECEPT.update=1


                }
            }


        }
override fun sendData() {
        Log.d("z2", "z2")
       replaceFragment(fragment3())
    }
```

Сам ресайкл

```
<!-- language: lang-kotlin -->

    fun create_recycle() {

                        recicle_view_recept.apply {
                            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                            adapter = DataAdapter(Massiv)

                        }

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если там интерфейс в конструкторе - у вас есть 3 пути.

- Создать класс, который будет имплеменировать этот интерфейс. В нем описать действия на клик. Создать экземпляр этого интерфейса в вашем активити/фрагменте и передать его в адаптер.
- Реализовать интерфейс прям в активити/фрагменте. А в адаптер передать this
- Создать анонимный класс который реализует ваш интерфейс.

  ```
  new DataAdapter(someList, new Click(){
      // override methods of class Click
  });
  ```

Comment: Cпасибо большое, получилось.